# A function that is not a derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

If this is possible, could somebody give me an example of a function $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb{R}$ continuous in $[a,b]$ but that THERE IS NOT a function, namely G, such that its derivative is the funciont f? i.e., such that
$$G'=f.$$

Comment: I don't think that this is possible... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: See [Volterra's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function). $($This comment is addressed at the answers below, rather than at the actual OP$)$.

Comment: @Lucian If I'm reading that article correctly, $V'$ (the derivative of Volterra's function) is discontinuous, meaning that the OP's $f$ cannot be $V'$.

Comment: @jpmc26:  Might be more useful to consider $f = V$.  (Some shifting and scaling may be required if $[a,b]$ is "boring".)

Answer (score 15):

This isn't possible: Every such function is a derivative. For any continuous function $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$, we can define the function
$$G(x) := \int_a^x f(t) \,dt,$$
and by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$G'(x) = f(x).$$
(This assumes that we define the derivative of a function at the endpoint of an interval to be the value of the appropriate one-sided limit.)

Answer (score 8):

It's impossible. Since $f$ is a continuous function, we can define
$$G(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$$
and the fundamental theorem of calculus says that $G$ is differentiable and $G'=f$.

Answer (score 7):

Mathematically, the antiderivative of every such $f$ exists, as in the integral expressions seen in other answers.

Practically speaking, though,  most examples of $f$ have no [closed-form expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for the antiderivative in terms of elementary functions.  (This statement can be made precise with Galois Theory)

One such case is given on the Wikipedia page.  Take
$$
f(x) = e^{-x^2}
$$
When we need a value for $\int_0^tf(x)dx$, we have to [do some approximating](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_299.htm) (Abramowitz and Stegun).

In practice, almost any "tricky" function you make up is unlikely to have a closed-form expression for its integral.  I'll make one up now, and I'm willing to bet there is no closed-form expression:
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{\tan(\log(x))}
$$

Comment: Good job answering what might be the actual question.  I believe the usual term for the functions you are thinking of is [*elementary* functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).   [*Simple* functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function) are something different.

Comment: Good catch, Matthew, and so edited.

Answer (score 0):

Stated very simply:

A function $f$ that is continuous is (Riemann) integrable. Therefore, it's integral will be a function whose derivative is $f$.

Sometimes, however, the integral is nonelementary! We may not be able to write it down in closed-form.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not pretty sure but this could be what you are looking for:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: This is an example of a function that is continuous everywhere and differentiable nowhere, not a function that doesn't have an antiderivative.